# PingFederate SLO: How can I receive more attributes in the token when I reach an SP logout service?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, pingfederate

As expected, when I initiate single-log-out (SLO), I reach various SP logout service endpoints.

However, I'd like to receive more information from the opentoken.

Currently, my SPs receive the following attributes in the token:

`not-before

subject

not-on-or-after

renew-until`

My Question:

- How can I receive more attributes in the token when I reach an SP logout service?

---

**EDIT:** Per @Scott T.'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8291271/109941):

> Having access to these attributes at SLO time implies that your
>   opentoken is sent in a cookie or that you are maintaining these
>   attributes locally at the SP in its application session.

- In my configuration, I have both IdP and SP adapters.
- I've added attributes to the extended contract *in each of these adapters*.
- So why is it that when I reach my IdP adapter's Logout Service, and I parse the open token, that I see *all attributes*, including those in the extended contract?

  - Whereas, I don't see *any extended contract attributes* in the parsed open token, when I reach *any* of the SP adapter logout services?
- Are IdP adapter logout services *special* in that fashion?

Answer (score 1):

Attributes received in an opentoken are dictated by the opentoken's attribute contract and its corresponding connection's attribute contract (and fulfillment).

For details on changing your opentoken adapter attribute contract (at the SP), see [this section](https://support.pingidentity.com/s/document-item?bundleId=pingfederate-92&topicId=adminGuide/configuringTheSpOpenTokenAdapter.html) in the PingFederate Administration Guide.

For details on changing your connection's attribute configuration, see [this section](https://support.pingidentity.com/s/document-item?bundleId=pingfederate-92&topicId=adminGuide%2FattributeContracts.html).

Note that this configuration only alters how attributes are received / passed into the opentoken at the SP during SSO.  Having access to these attributes at SLO time implies that your opentoken is sent in a cookie or that you are maintaining these attributes locally at the SP in its application session.  Keep in mind that cookies have size limitations so if you are in fact using it to transport your opentoken then you may hit such a limit as you increase the amount of attributes passed around.

Also note that if you want new attributes from the IdP, you will similarly need to adjust configuration on that side of your connection.

If you are looking for more training on the PingFederate integration kits, I encourage you to register for [Ping Identity training](https://www.pingidentity.com/en/resources/training.html).

Comment: There is no concept of "SLO service" from an OpenToken adapter perspective.  OpenToken's are used just during SSO to pass around attributes.  If you've extended your contract on the adapter, you will need to examine the connection (IdP and SP connection) configurations to include such attributes as well.  The connection contains details about how that attribute is fulfilled.